# Cannot PuTTY into Hyper-V VM (Ubuntu 18 server)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, putty, hyper-v

An Ubuntu 18.04 server virtual machine in Hyper-V refuses connections via PuTTY. The guest is running & can be pinged from the host (Windows 10, 1903). The server is freshly built from an iso. Openssh-server was installed during installation.

Server shows that it's listening on port 22. PuTTY will connect to remote systems. Using WSL to ssh into the server also results in Connection refused. PuTTY will also connect to VirtualBox VMs when that is used. (I'm trying to evaluate Hyper-V and am not yet amused!)

Edit: what may be a related issue is that after installing Apache2 & browsing to the VM's IP address I get the host, not the guest. The guest's adapter has a static IP address and is configured as an external switch on the host's adapter. So I'm trying to ssh to the host from the host? **W**hat **T**otal **F**un!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved: there was a conflict/confusion with an earlier attempt to fix the issue. I ended up disabling a VirtualBox adapter at the host.